# NodeJS script with async/await causing syntax error (v7.10.0)

Tags: node.js, async-await, syntax-error

I am trying to use async/await in NodeJS but my script is throwing a syntax error.

I was under the impression that async/await is [supported naively since Node 7.6](https://www.infoq.com/news/2017/02/node-76-async-await). When I run `node -v` I get `v7.10.0`.

Here is the contents of `index.js`:

```
async function getValueAsync() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        resolve('foo');
    });
}

let value = await getValueAsync();
console.log(value);
```

But when I invoke this script with `node index.js` I get:

```
let value = await getValueAsync();
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at createScript (vm.js:53:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:95:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:543:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:427:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:151:9)
```

I am running Linux Mint 18.1.

How can I get my script to compile and run?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`await` is only valid inside `async` functions, so you need, for example, an async [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) to wrap your code with:

```
void async function() {
  let value = await getValueAsync();
  console.log(value);
}();
```

And, since return values from `async` functions are wrapped by a promise, you can shorten `getValueAsync` to simply this:

```
async function getValueAsync() {
  return 'foo';
}
```

Or don't mark it as `async` and return a promise from it:

```
function getValueAsync() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    resolve('foo');
  });
}
```

Comment: but according to [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) an `await` could also be used on a function that returns a `Promise`. Actually `async`makes the function return a `promise`. So I got confused.

Comment: ok, I got it, `await` must always be inserted into `async` functions. According to doc. the `await` expression causes `async` function execution to pause until a `Promise` is fulfilled or rejected, and to resume execution of the `async` function after fulfillment. When resumed, the value of the `await` expression is that of the fulfilled `Promise`. Therefore I can never have a top lever `await` declaration.