# Encrypt password in NodeJs in the same way Drupal 7 Does

Tags: node.js, drupal, password-encryption

I am trying to migrate data present in Drupal 7 to a nodeJs platform,
The passwords stored in Drupal needs to be stored in the same format(in encrypted format, as they cannot get decoded).
So, for existing data(user), I need the same password hashing technique, so that the password should match when existing user will try to login.

Summarised requirement : password stored in nodeJs platform : "some hashed password"

password entered by user : "plain text"

so that : hash(plain text) === "some hashed password"

I found one nodeJs Library `Drupal Hash`, but seems like it is not working.

Fragment of code that I tried:

```
var password = 'Hello@123';
var hashedExpectedPassword = '$S$DzjvIwyAB.A9CzV96g2GsE/hLzkXBI3OZdgGhZJBBJwDQANh.JuV'
var passwordHash = drupalHash.hashPassword(password).toString(`hex`);
console.log(passwordHash); ////$S$DW16ZF0m/1a3VRRp8ZT26jdjHEd4lwBMCoGyCfsOsQqMDF6w36j3
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to encrypt the password in node.js with bcrypt package.
The code is shown below:

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
const saltRounds = 10


const password = 'myPassword$123'
console.log('password', password)
const anotherPassword = 'anotherPassword$123'
const hashedPassword = bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds)
console.log('hashedPassword', hashedPassword)

void (async function () {
  let value = await bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds);
  console.log('hash value', value);

  let isPasswordMatching = await bcrypt.compareSync(password, value); // true
  console.log('isPasswordMatching', isPasswordMatching);
  isPasswordMatching = await bcrypt.compareSync(anotherPassword, value);//false
  console.log('isPasswordMatching', isPasswordMatching);
})();
```

The following reference links for the above code are usefull. Please check these.

1. https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44098013/nodejs-script-with-async-await-causing-syntax-error-v7-10-0

Comment: I have tried this method as well but the passwords are not matched, the requirement is of cloning password hashing technique from Drupal7 to NodeJs.